# Detect mobile phones vs. non-phone mobile devices?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, mobile, jquery-mobile

Before you ignore this post, I've read countless posts on how to use screen resolution, user agents, and the like to detect mobile platform as whether to display a "full featured" or larger website vs. a smaller one.

I am using .Net MVC4 and can already redirect to my .mobile pages via global.asax.cs and _Layout.Mobile files without a hitch.

My question is thus:
Once on a mobile page, I'd like to know whether this is a phone of tablet (iPad, Android, etc) in order to render a "Call Us" button on the page.  I am using jQueryMobile so I've got the code so far to do the following:

```
<a href="tel:+15559876543" data-role="button">Call Us Today</a>
```

Basically I am checking to see if the device has a radio and can make calls, so as not to frustrate that WiFi-only iPad user who clicks on a "Call Us" link and doesn't get anywhere.

I am entirely cognizant of the fact that there may be a better approach to what I am doing, and I am gratefully open to those suggestions as well.

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341637/how-do-detect-android-tablets-in-general-useragent there doesn't seem to be a perfect strategy for this. a best-effort attempt is probably your best bet

Comment: Use javascript thats enough...

Comment: suresh - Yes, javascript is definitely an option.  The question is how to decide whether the device can make calls.  Screen resolution is a moving target on newer platforms and it is harder to tell a tablet from a phone from Request.Browser.ScreenPixels...  Or is there some snippet of Javascript you are referring to that I am unaware of? - Dan

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "call us today" text with the phone number.  (IMO) this makes it a lot more obvious what the button would do if I clicked it, allows me to click it on my iPad if I want to add it to my contacts, or pickup the phone next to me and ring it as I can actually see the  number.

Comment: The text actually says Call "Company Name", so I think the purpose of the button is intuitive enough.  I am concerned, and researching having the phone # in plain text so as not to get skimmed by bots.  Or is this not an issue anymore?  Anyhow, that is a thought for another thread.