# Android: smartphone or tablet

Tags: javascript, android, webserver, browser

When receiving a web request from an Android device, is there a way to know if it comes from a smartphone or from a tablet? If any Javascript tweak must be pre-applied - good as well.

Comment: Shouldn't you care more about technical characteristics, like physical screen size, rather than whether the marketing blurbs use the word "phone", "tablet", "phablet", etc.?

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet

Comment: Try taking a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341637/how-do-detect-android-tablets-in-general-useragent

Comment: @PranavKapoor I am asking about the Web side, not applications.

Comment: @Dimse so the only thing is `mobile Android` vs `Android`?

Comment: It would seem like it, yes. Would love for there to be a more elegant solution, but so very few things about the internet are elegant..

Comment: @Dimse checked, haven't seen `mobile Android` anywhere here in reports

Answer (score 0):

basically by checking the useragent

[this does not work in all cases (search for Mobile)](http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings/dv/brand125579/samsung-galaxy-tab-3), but almost all cases and should work in future releases even better. The only exception from above seems to be a uncommon browser that was used on the tablet.

js

```
var appv= navigator.appVersion.toLowerCase();
if(appv.search("android") > -1 && !(appv.search("mobile"))){
  //is android tablet
}else if (appv.search("android") > -1){
  //is android phone
}
```