# window.orientation detection for handheld only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code on my webapp to display a div only in landscape orientation.  It works great on a phone, but it also works great on an iPad, which I don't want.  Is there a way to have this function work only on handhelds?

```
$(function(){
window.onload = handleOrientation;
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', handleOrientation, false);
        function handleOrientation() {
            if (window.orientation == "90" || window.orientation == "-90") {
            document.getElementById("landscape").style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("landscape").style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
});
```

I'm a total newb at javascript, learning and learning as fast as I can thanks to you guys, but I don't know what to do on this one.

Comment: you can check against width of the device screen. If it's less than your threshold for handheld device only then attach the listener.

Comment: @Ehtesham You should write that in an answer.

Comment: Why don't you style the div with css media queries, that's what they are for.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to differentiate between phones and tablets and then disable it for tablets.

One way to differentiate is by finding out the screen width.

```
if (window.screen.width < 320) {
// This is an iphone
// 320 pixels is the width of an iphone
// do the necessary
}
```

This is probably not the best way, but fixes the problem

Comment: Some Android phones have width of 480 or more... iPhone is not the only phone on the market anymore.

Comment: @strah I just gave an example. You could use 480px instead. Still 320px iPhone would work and the tablets wont.

Comment: How about HD phones (1920×1080)? How you tell them from tablets?

Comment: So far I am going with this, just for the ease of it.  I have it set to 580 and it works with apple products, I'll test android over the next few days.  On very high-res screens, my site works well enough, and based on analytics I have very little android phone usage, less than 3% anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do some user agent sniffing, as it is almost impossible to tell apart phones and tablets just by checking the screen size/pixel density. And even user agent is not 100% reliable.

You may find some inspiration here: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: I was trying to avoid listing all the user agents and was hoping the was a way to detect handheld.

Comment: iPad **is** a handheld :-) So is iPad mini, Nexus 7 and many more... User agent sniffing is bad, but that's the only solution if you want to target devices precisely.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about iPad as tablet. You can check for the user agent of browser and attach the listener only if it's phone. Otherwise check if it's a mobile device with user agent string.

```
if (!navigator.userAgent.test(/iPad/i)) {
    // Attcah listener here
}
```

Check answers to following question for how to detect with user agent strings.

[How do detect Android Tablets in general. Useragent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341637/how-do-detect-android-tablets-in-general-useragent)