# rewriting url for tablet and smart phone

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm using Apache's rewrite url. .htaccess file contains following redirect rules. My requirement is that, when ever I hit on the url `www.temp.com/card`, based on the device it should internally call that particular `.do`.

For Example, from a smart phone if i type `www.temp.com/card` internally it should call  `www.temp.com/pa/spCard.do`.

I tried with the below rules but problem is that some tablets having android, so in tablet it always going into smarphone `.do`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^card/?$ /pa/spCard.do?uri=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ipad" [NC]
RewriteRule ^card/?$ /pa/tabCard.do?uri=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^card/?$ /pa/webCard.do?uri=$1 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Is there any way we can distinguish between an Android mobile and tablet (using user agent string)?

Comment: Please guys, anyone can help in this ?

Answer (score 2):

You must stop further rewriting by adding the [`L`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) flag, when you have detected a device

```
RewriteRule ^card/?$ /pa/spCard.do?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And you don't have `$1` captured anywhere in the rewrite rules. Furthermore, the URL is always `card`, so you can reduce the rule to

```
RewriteRule ^card/?$ /pa/spCard.do [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^card/?$ /pa/spCard.do?uri=$0 [L,QSA]
```

if you need the `uri` parameter.

Same with `tabCard.do` and `webCard.do`, of course.

To distingiush between Android phones and tablets, see [Chrome for Android User-Agent](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/user-agent). This does not hold for all tablets, unfortunately. But at least, you can weed out some of the tablets by specifying `android.*mobile` with the first rule and just `android` with the second

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android.*mobile|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile [NC]
RewriteRule ^card/?$ /pa/spCard.do?uri=$0 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|ipad [NC]
RewriteRule ^card/?$ /pa/tabCard.do?uri=$0 [L,QSA]
```

With these conditions, you will know that you have a tablet in the second rule and a phone *or* tablet in the first rule.

Comment: :Is there any way we can distinguish between an  mobile and tablet (using user agent string)? tried a few rules, but its difficult to distinguish between an Android mobile and tablet .

Comment: @Rosh The difference seems to be `Mobile`, see https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/user-agent for details. Although, there seem to be tablets having `Mobile` in their user agent string, see the comments to this answer for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344382/1741542

Comment: checked with android tablet and phone. Tablet user agent is having mobile in it.