# With userAgent.match(), what does the "/i" mean at the end?

Tags: javascript, agent

Examples can be found at these locations:

[JavaScript how to check User Agent for Mobile/Tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757105/javascript-how-to-check-user-agent-for-mobile-tablet)

### [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

For the problem I am working on, I will not be using Javascript to detect the user agent, so the answer does not directly affect my problem.  However, while searching for the correct user agents, I kept seeing "/iPad/i", "/iPhone/i", "/Android/i" and so on.  What does the "/i" mean after "/iPad"?  Is it simply a regular expression, and to tell the Javascript function to be case insensitive?

I tried googling for userAgent.match() to get more information about the function itself, and to see what arguments it accepts, but I had no luck.

To elaborate: I've read a few sites that say user agent sniffing is bad news, so if you're wondering why I'm sniffing user agent, it's to compile a list of email addresses.  Mac uses commas, Windows uses semi-colons.  I recently became aware that iOS also uses commas, so my program was breaking on iPad.  So, I need to update my user agent sniffing code.

Comment: Ignore alphabetic case, so that `A` and `a` are considered equal. And yes, it's "simply a regular expression".

Comment: Thanks!  If you want to put that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: [MDN RegExp documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, I'll add this to my reading list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It meant as case insensitive

so `"/iPhone/i"` will match with `iphone`, `IPHONE` or `IpHOne`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a regular expression to `match` in 2 ways, either by creating a new instance of a RegExp object:

```
var re = new RegExp('pattenToMatch', 'i');
string.match(re);
```

or by using the shorthand as mentioned above - notice there are no double quotes surrounding a shorthand regex:

```
string.match(/iPhone/i);
```

In the first example, the second argument will contain any flags - eg i for case insensitive, g for global. In the second example, any flags are included after the last slash.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any difference, other than the shorthand is less typing.  Does the second example not allow more than one flag?

Comment: first example allows you to use a variable as part of your regex. eg var re = new RegExp('\S+' + variable + '\S+', 'g'); You aren't able to achieve this with the shorthand way.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense,  thanks for the clarification!