# How to find in which device (mobile(android or Ios) or desktop) the web application is opened

Tags: android, jquery, ios, angularjs, mobile

I am working on the web application project using angularjs which it has the mobile applications too they are android and Ios. Now i want when the web application is open in mobile i need to find the device type and check the mobile app is installed or not, if installed should open in mobile app, if not a download button is there for app-link.Thanks in advance

Comment: this is all extremely well documented online, please do some research before asking questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript how to check User Agent for Mobile/Tablet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757105/javascript-how-to-check-user-agent-for-mobile-tablet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$window` services,

you can check like this one

```
var userAgent = $window.navigator.userAgent;

/(iPhone|iPad|iPod).* OS 9_\d/.test(userAgent) && !/Version\/9\./.test(userAgent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkOperatingSystem()
{  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

    //Check mobile device is Android
    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        //Add your Code here
    }

    //Check mobile device is IOS
    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        //Add your Code here
    }

    //Check device os is Windows (For Laptop and PC)
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1)
    {
        //Add your Code here
    }

    //Check device os is MAC (For Laptop and PC)
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1)
    {
        //Add your Code here
    }
}
```