# Angular 4 router-outlets

Tags: angular, router, outlet, angular4-router

I am quite new in Angular 4. I am trying to use router outlet to create dynamic content unfortunately, I am not able to use it twice, because I have different scenarios for tablets, mobiles and desktops. Maybe do you guys have some advise?

**I think I can assign different outlets** *but maybe there is an easier way?*

My code:

```
<div class="ui two column stackable grid">

    <app-navigation class="three wide column computer mobile only webso-navigation"></app-navigation>
    <app-navigation class="four wide column tablet only webso-navigation"></app-navigation>
    <div class="thirteen wide column computer mobile only webso-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="twelve wide column tablet only webso-content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div> 



</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: may be you can try 'named router outlet'. http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/

Comment: use named routes - `{
  path: 'compose',
  component: ComposeMessageComponent,
  outlet: 'popup'
},` , `<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['compose'] } }]">Contact</a>` , `<router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>` https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, there is no need of two `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

You can simply achieve this by using ngClass

```
// In Component File
isMobile : boolean;
isTablet : boolean;

// In Template File
<div [ngClass]="{'thirteen wide column computer mobile only webso-content' : isMobile , 
                'twelve wide column tablet only webso-content' : isTablet }" >
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

But if you still want to use multiple `router-outlet` ,

Checkout the link as @Skeptor suggested in comment
http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/

Comment: But somehow I should check the viewport / resolution? To assign boolean values for isMobile || isTablet

Comment: @user2149578 , there are so many libs out there for device recognition, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757105/javascript-how-to-check-user-agent-for-mobile-tablet

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

App.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  title = 'app';
  innerWidth;

  isTablet : boolean = false;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;

    this.innerWidth <= 600 || this.innerWidth >= 1024 ? this.isTablet = false : this.isTablet = true;
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;

    this.innerWidth <= 600 || this.innerWidth >= 1024 ? this.isTablet = false : this.isTablet = true;

  }
```

App.component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="isTablet ? 'twelve wide column tablet only webso-content'
                                : 'thirteen wide column computer mobile only webso-content'">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```