# URL redirection to Mobile site

Tags: android, iis, mobile, user-agent

since the user agent for Android Mobile and Android Tablet are the same, I am not able to filter Android Tablet requests, so that I could redirect to desktop version instead of mobile site..

IIS 7

```
for {HTTP_USER_AGENT}

blackberry|iphone|ipod|android|windows\ ce|htc|midp|j2me|palm|nokia|symbian|sonyeric|motorola|motorazr|motorizr|motorokr|mot\-|moto(v|e|q).+|samsung|^sch\-|^sgh\-|^lg\-
```

Comment: *since the user agent for Android Mobile and Android Tablet are the same* Incorrect. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344382/188331

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect. Mobile Android has "Mobile" string in the User-Agent header. Tablet Android does not

see this
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344382/