# Magento 2 : Varnish Cache based on user agents

Tags: varnish, magento2.2

I have a site with Magento 2.2.2 Varnish enabled

Based on php snippet code which detects device based on user agents,i am printing "IN Desktop" in desktop & "In mobile"
in mobile device.

But once the page is cached,it is printing the "IN Desktop" both in desktop & mobile

Actual Result should be like "In Desktop" should be printed in desktop & "In mobile" should be provided in mobile

Is there any possibility to generate different caches based on the user agents

I have placed devicedetect.vcl file under var/ Please find its content

```
sub devicedetect {
    unset req.http.X-UA-Device;
    set req.http.X-UA-Device = "pc";

    # Handle that a cookie may override the detection alltogether.
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(?i)X-UA-Device-force") {
        /* ;?? means zero or one ;, non-greedy to match the first. */
        set req.http.X-UA-Device = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "(?i).*X-UA-Device-force=([^;]+);??.*", "\1");
        /* Clean up our mess in the cookie header */
        set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|; ) *X-UA-Device-force=[^;]+;? *", "\1");
        /* If the cookie header is now empty, or just whitespace, unset it. */
        if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^ *$") { unset req.http.Cookie; }
    } else {
        if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "\(compatible; Googlebot-Mobile/2.1; \+http://www.google.com/bot.html\)" ||
            (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(Android|iPhone)" && req.http.User-Agent ~ "\(compatible.?; Googlebot/2.1.?; \+http://www.google.com/bot.html") ||
            (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(iPhone|Windows Phone)" && req.http.User-Agent ~ "\(compatible; bingbot/2.0; \+http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm")) {
            set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-bot"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)(ads|google|bing|msn|yandex|baidu|ro|career|seznam|)bot" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)(baidu|jike|symantec)spider" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)scanner" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)(web)crawler") {
            set req.http.X-UA-Device = "bot"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)ipad")        { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-ipad"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)ip(hone|od)") { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-iphone"; }
        /* how do we differ between an android phone and an android tablet?
           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341637/how-do-detect-android-tablets-in-general-useragent */
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)android.*(mobile|mini)") { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-android"; }
        // android 3/honeycomb was just about tablet-only, and any phones will probably handle a bigger page layout.
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)android 3")              { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-android"; }
        /* Opera Mobile */
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Opera Mobi")                  { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-smartphone"; }
        // May very well give false positives towards android tablets. Suggestions welcome.
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)android")         { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-android"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet")         { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-rim"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "hp-tablet.*TouchPad")         { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-hp"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Kindle/3")         { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-kindle"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Touch.+Tablet PC" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "Windows NT [0-9.]+; ARM;" ) {
                set req.http.X-UA-Device = "tablet-microsoft";
        }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Mobile.+Firefox")     { set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-firefoxos"; }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "^HTC" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "Fennec" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "IEMobile" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "BlackBerry" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "BB10.*Mobile" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "GT-.*Build/GINGERBREAD" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "SymbianOS.*AppleWebKit") {
            set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-smartphone";
        }
        elsif (req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)symbian" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^sonyericsson" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^nokia" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^samsung" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)^lg" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)bada" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)blazer" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)cellphone" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)iemobile" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)midp-2.0" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)u990" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)netfront" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)opera mini" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)palm" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)nintendo wii" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)playstation portable" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)portalmmm" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)proxinet" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)sonyericsson" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)symbian" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)windows\ ?ce" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)winwap" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)eudoraweb" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)htc" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)240x320" ||
            req.http.User-Agent ~ "(?i)avantgo") {
            set req.http.X-UA-Device = "mobile-generic";
        }
    }
}
```

Please find the default.vcl file as follows:

```
vcl 4.0;
include "/home/nthrive/public_html/var/devicedetect.vcl";


import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 4.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    call devicedetect;
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unkown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove Google gclid parameters to minimize the cache objects
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }

}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    if (bereq.http.X-UA-Device) {
        if (!beresp.http.Vary) { # no Vary at all
            set beresp.http.Vary = "X-UA-Device";
        } elsif (beresp.http.Vary !~ "X-UA-Device") { # add to existing Vary
            set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary + ", X-UA-Device";
        }
    }
    # comment this out if you don't want the client to know your classification
    set beresp.http.X-UA-Device = bereq.http.X-UA-Device;

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    # images, css and js are cacheable by default so we have to remove cookie also
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
       # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if ((req.http.X-UA-Device) && (resp.http.Vary)) {
        set resp.http.Vary = regsub(resp.http.Vary, "X-UA-Device", "User-Agent");
    }
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (fetch);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

Please find the $_SERVER variable as follows:

```
Array
(
    [USER] => nthrive
    [HOME] => /home/nthrive
    [HTTP_X_VARNISH] => 394057
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip
    [HTTP_GRACE] => none
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => 183.82.110.21, 183.82.110.21, 127.0.0.1
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; mage-translation-file-version=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; mage-messages=; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; recently_compared_product=%7B%7D; recently_compared_product_previous=%7B%7D; product_data_storage=%7B%7D; store=default; mage-cache-sessid=true; section_data_ids=%7B%22cart%22%3A1523515008%7D
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
    [HTTP_REFERER] => http://nthrive.mm.dotcomweavers.net/contact/
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/64.0.3282.140 Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => 183.82.110.21
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST] => nthrive.mm.dotcomweavers.net
    [HTTP_HOST] => nthrive.mm.dotcomweavers.net
    [UNIQUE_ID] => 51890.1
    [MAGE_RUN_TYPE] => store
    [MAGE_RUN_CODE] => 
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/nthrive/public_html//pub/index.php
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [SERVER_NAME] => nthrive.mm.dotcomweavers.net
    [SERVER_PORT] => 8080
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 28481
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.10.2
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/nthrive/public_html//pub
    [DOCUMENT_URI] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /test.html
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => 
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1523528507.3393
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1523528507
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure that Varnish sees mobile and desktop pages as different things. This is achieved through the use of `Vary:` header.

You should use [devicedetect](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-devicedetect) instead of detecting device in the PHP code.

Alll you need to do is implement [sending the detected device type to Magento](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-devicedetect/blob/master/INSTALL.rst#example-1-send-http-header-to-backend). This snippet takes care of varying cache by device class as well as device class detection.

Now, in Magento you can remove your device detection code and simply rely on the value of HTTP header `X-UA-Device`. It will have either values of `pc`, `mobile-smartphone`, `mobile-generic`, `bot` or `tablet-microsoft`.

Comment: Thanks for your info.I have followed the above steps and but i am not receiving the "X-UA-Device" in http headers.Please find the default.vcl and device-detect.vcl in my edited question.

Comment: I have placed both default.vcl and devicedetect.vcl file under var folder

Comment: All seem OK to me. Try to dump `$_SERVER` variable in PHP. The `X-UA-Device` should be there. It might appear as `HTTP_X_UA_DEVICE`.

Comment: No i am not able to receive HTTP_X_UA_DEVICE in the $_SERVER variable.Please find the $_SERVER variable values in my edited question

Comment: You might have forgotten to reload or restart varnish. It's also best to place devicedetect in `/etc/varnish/devicedetect.vcl` as it's not user specific.

Comment: Restarted Varnish.Also placed file in /etc/varnish/devicedetect.vcl But Still no luck

Comment: This is working fine.There was an error in the varnish file.Thanks for your support